# Changing tab select when body link clicked

Tags: jquery

I have a simple tab script for alternating between content. Currently the script enables a change on the class of the tab when it is clicked, but I want to link to the tabs from within the tab body copy and ensure that the active tab receives the proper class to be selected.

http://jsfiddle.net/jdmcculley/aMBj2/2/

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.tabs a').click(function(){
        switch_tabs($(this));
    });

    switch_tabs($('.defaulttab'));

    $('.tab-content .img-frame a').click(function(){
        switch_tabs($(this));
    });

});

function switch_tabs(obj)
{
    $('.tab-content').hide();
    $('.tabs a').removeClass("selected");
    var id = obj.attr("rel");

    $('#'+id).show();
    obj.addClass("selected");
}
```

Comment: What is the "proper" class? In my answer I remove the 'selected' class from the old tab and add it to the new tab. Are there other classes that need to be swapped when changing tabs?

Answer (score 0):

**CSS**

```
.selected {
    background-color: #387C2B !important;
    border: 1px solid #006633 !important;
}
```

**Javascript**

```
$('.tabs a').click(function(){
    switch_tabs($(this));
});

switch_tabs($('.defaulttab'));

$('.tab-content .img-frame a').click(function(){
    switch_tabs($(this));
});


function switch_tabs(obj)
{
    $('.tab-content').hide();
    $('.tabs a').removeClass("green").removeClass("selected").addClass("gray");
    var id = obj.attr("rel");

    $('#'+id).show();
    obj.addClass("selected").removeClass("gray");
}
```

**Working Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/aMBj2/4/

Comment: Both tabs turn grey if you click the Chicago link in the Overview div.

Comment: Thanks Kevin, so that did remove the selected class, but there are still some issues I can't figure out.  How do I set the "Chicago" tab to be selected.  Also, when the link to Chicago in the "Overview" tab body is clicked it turns green. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to replace this:

```
 obj.addClass("selected");
```

with this:

```
 $('a[rel='+id+']').addClass("selected");
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/aMBj2/5/)**